# How to set position with css method in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My default values for `.csw-step4-price-summary` div is

```
.csw-step4-price-summary {
    width: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 661px;
    right: 40px;
}
```

When I want to do the following, it does change position to fixed, but it does not react to bottom and right values.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();

if (y > 220) {
    $(".csw-step4-price-summary").css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'bottom': '661',
        'right': '140'
    });

} else {
    $(".csw-step4-price-summary").css({ 'position': 'absolute'});
}
```

});

Any suggestions why this might be happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add "px" to the value in the .css method

Comment: You're missing `px` from the position values. I'd also suggest you simplify your logic by putting those values in a class, then just call `toggleClass()` as needed. Closing as a typo

Comment: If `px` is the desired unit, you can pass a number as the value to `bottom` or `right` and jQuery will apply `px`. i.e. `'bottom': 661`.

Comment: I have a problem with this. It all works fine in a 100% resolution, but once i zoom in or out, it price-summary changes its position a little. I have even tried percent as value of bottom or right without success.

Answer (score 2):

Try using 'px' in the unit in the css function

```
$(".csw-step4-price-summary").css({
    'position': 'fixed',
        'bottom': '661px',
        'right': '140px'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

it's

```
 'bottom': '661px',
  'right': '140px'
```